# Performance cost of dynamic class loading in JAVA

Tags: java, tomcat, dynamic-class-loaders

I develop applications using a customized version of Tomcat.
There is support for dynamic class loading, which I use a lot in test and development environments, and I'm curious about the impact of using it in production environment also.

By my knowledge, dynamic class loading is not to be used in production due to performance issues, due to the class loader polling classes at each access.

But, this applcation server support configuration of polling frequency for loading new classes.

If I understand it correctly, if I configure the dynamic class loading to poll every reasonably large amount of time (ie. 1hour) I should avoid most adverse performance impacts.

In production, this mechanism would be used in a limited number of ways:
1) emergency patching without user downtime (fixes would be released at the first shutdown)
2) permanent patching of classes of which we do not have the source (legacy third party libs)

Is this a reliable solution?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't heard of a "polling frequency", so I am not sure where you got that from. Wouldn't it be easier to just use the Tomcat Manager Application to trigger a reload when required?

Comment: It's a feature of this "customized version of Tomcat", which really is more like a bigger application server, which uses Tomcat for a part of its functions.

Comment: I am not sure what you gain by having the classes reloaded on an hourly basis, when you could just as well reload them when required via the Manager.

Comment: Tomcat is integrate in some obscure manner, I don't know if I can trigger the reload, so I was thinking about a compromise between constant polling and night-time releases.  
Being able to tell the customers "in an hour the patch will be online" is better than "wait until tomorrow to have the patch online".   
  
Anyway, I'm gonna explore the possibility to trigger the reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you should not use the feature for production. 
Apart from the polling overhead there may be lot of other scenario which would not cause problems in a dev environment

Few things that come to my mind are

1. Impact on any constants that are inlined during compiletime
2. Impact on perm space
3. You lose track of the version you have deployed in production
4. there can be mistakes like missing a classfile during the patch

Comment: 1 and 2 may be problematic, 3 and 4 I think can be solved enforcing release policies. Thanks for pointing out those issues.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what "customized Tomcat version" you have it is obviously difficult to tell if you understand it correctly. However yes, if it does what it says on the tin, you will be avoiding most advers effects.

Still for Emergegency Pachting and the like, why would you want to wait up to an hour for the classes to be reloaded when you could just use the Tomcat Manager Application as described below?

If you want to use this feature for Emergency patching or generell patching, I would strongly suggest using Tomcat Manager Application to trigger a reload when requried:

> reloadable
>
> Set to true if you want Catalina to monitor classes in
>   /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for changes, and automatically
>   reload the web application if a change is detected. This feature is
>   very useful during application development, but it requires
>   significant runtime overhead and is not recommended for use on
>   deployed production applications. That's why the default setting for
>   this attribute is false. You can use the Manager web application,
>   however, to trigger reloads of deployed applications on demand.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Comment: It's a pretty obscure third party application server, which uses tomcat somewhere in the innards. I've still to determine if it's tomcat itself who manages class loading. Ah, the bitter taste of legacy software...

Comment: Does it really take that long to deploy a new war? Considering all the issues listed by basiljames, I would suggest restarting rather than trying to hack some kind of hot deployment or if it is really that critical have a cluster where you update one at a time.

Comment: Downtime is not really an option, too many users in too many different locations. Clustering, I think has never been tried with this app-server. That's why I'm looking for alternatives.